# Unable to complete Oracle example for ODI Flat File to Flat File Export

Tags: database, oracle, etl, data-integration, oracle-data-integrator

Hi I am new to ODI and I have installed ODI 11g and have created Master and Work Repositories using the Oracle tutorial
[here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/odi/odi_11g/odi_master_work_repos/odi_master_work_repos.htm)

After this I followed the tutorial they have provided [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/odi/odi_11g/odi_project_ff-to-ff/odi_project_flatfile-to-flatfile.htm) to create ODI Project and Interface for exporting a Flat File to a Flat File. I was able to execute several steps in this tutorial before I reached at **step 4** under the heading **Creating a New ODI Interface for Flat File to Flat File Transformations**

Here is the mapping flow which I got after following all the steps in this tutorial and it is totally different from what they showed in this step: [image]

As per this tutorial I am supposed to **Click the SS_0 (1 - FILE_GENERIC) source datastore. This makes the properties for the source appear below. In the LKM Selector section, select LKM File to SQL from the LKM drop-down list if not already selected.** but I cant see anything like that.

Please help if anyone knows the reason for this. May be I am missing something or would have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed a part of the second step of that section.

Click on the Overview tab and choose "In-Memory Engine: SUNOPSIS_MEMORY_ENGINE" as your staging area.
Then go back on the flow tab and you should see three separated groups instead of one.
Click on the Datastore of the group in the middle (the Staging Area) and there you can set your LKM.

The reason we need to select a different staging area is because usually ODI will try to let the underlying technologies doing most of the job. If you load an Oracle database, ODI will generate SQL code and let the database execute it itself. This is not possible with the File technology as a file can't execute code by itself. So instead we will do the transformation and the loading using the In-Memory Engine of ODI, the SUNOPSIS_MEMORY_ENGINE.

This SUNOPSIS_MEMORY_ENGINE is actually an HSQL Database. It's in the memory of the JVM of your agent (or ODI Studio if you use the local agent).

Comment: I actually resolved it. Anyways I am marking your solution as answer for the correct and nice explanation. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad you sorted it and the explanation was useful. Good luck in your ODI journey, I hope you will like that tool.